# Meaning of "unfreiwillig komisch"

Tags: meaning

From [Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/tv/tatort-aus-konstanz-mit-eva-mattes-als-klara-blum-a-993742.html):

> Psychologie mit dem Vorschlaghammer und ein Drehbuch, das in die Asservatenkammer gehört: "Winternebel", der witterungsaktive Entführungs-"Tatort" aus Konstanz, ist **unfreiwillig komisch**.

What does "unfreiwillig komisch" mean here? Even literally translated into English, it would be "involuntarily funny", which doesn't really make that much sense.

Comment: Seems ok to me. Something that ends up looking or being funny, even if that was not intended or intentional. Also beware that "komisch" can also mean "strange".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An idiomatic translation of **unfreiwillig komisch** would be

> **unintentionally hilarious**

but I guess the literal translation **involuntarily funny** can be understood, too: According to *Spiegel Online*, the *Tatort* crime movie is funny because it has a bad, laughable script (or is poorly acted) - although, by the producers, it is not meant to be funny.